# Multivariable Calculus Parametric Equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, parametric

**I have a homework question that I am just stuck on, I have been doing it for a while so I will show you what I have. 
Let $r(t) = (\sin 2t, \cos 2t, \sin2t\cos4t)$ . Find the point where $r(t) $intersects the $xy$-plane on the interval $1/2 π < t < 3/4 π.$**

What I did was:

I set: $\cos4t=0$ to get $\pi/8 +4n\pi, 3\pi/8 +4n\pi.$
I set: $\sin2t=0$ to get $\pi/2 +2n\pi.$

I know that the curve intersects the $xy$-plane at the points where z = 0. But what do I do next? Appreciate any help, I just want to know what I did wrong and where to proceed from this, I would like to understand how to get the answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers could be written a bit more compact (and correct):
$$\cos4t = 0 \implies 4t = \pi/2+n\pi \implies t = \pi/8 + n\pi/4.$$
Similarly:
$$\sin2t = 0 \implies t = n\pi/2.$$

You now need to find the value(s) of the integer $n$ that make $t$ fall into the given range. Once you have these values for $t$, plug it back in $r(t)$ to get the points (...,...,0) that belongs to $r(t)$ and lie on the $xy$-plane.

Comment: So, can I plug in pi/2?

Comment: No, because $\pi/2$ is the end point, but excluded from the given interval $(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{4})$. Hint: What integer value of $n$ would make $\pi/8+n\pi/4$ fall into this interval?

Comment: I'm not sure? I got 52/24, but thats not an integer.

Comment: You're close! That's ~2.16. Why don't you try $n=3$? What happens if $n=2$ or $n=4$? What would be the result?

Comment: I tried 3, I think that works, its between the interval?

Comment: Wait no, it does not work

Comment: n=2 works for the plugging in!

Comment: The value of $t$ is between the end points of the interval. In other words, when $n=2$, $t$ satisfies the condition: $\pi/2<t<3\pi/4$ given in the problem statement.

Comment: So now that I have 2, what do I do from there?

Comment: @Taffies1 Please read my suggested direction in the original post of the solution.

Comment: I dont really understand that, I found that n=2, but u said to plug it into r(t)? so what do i do? I get 5pi/8

Comment: When I plug that back in I get: (0, 1/8, 0) which is wrong I think.

Comment: $t = 5\pi/8$ is correct. However, you should check your work when plugging back into $r(t)$.

Comment: do i plug in 5pi/8 or 5pi/8 *2 so 10pi/8

Comment: At $t = 5\pi/8$, $r(t) = r(5\pi/8) = (\sin(2*5\pi/8), \cos(2*5\pi/8),\sin(2*5\pi/8)\cos(4*5\pi/8))$.

Comment: i got -{sqrt{2}/{2},-sqrt{2}/{2}, -1

Comment: never mind i got that answer, it is what i had, but z coordinate is 0. thank you for your help!

Comment: @Taffies1 You're welcome! Also, I would appreciate it if you accept this answer.

Comment: Oh yea, sorry I'm new, I forgot about that, will do right now!

Answer (score 0):

One of your values of $t$ falls into the range given $\pi/2<t<3\pi/4$.  Plug that value back into the parametric equations.